# Why does this event actually trigger?

Tags: vue.js

Im in a vue project using routing, its a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wy9q22isx3U
The repo with the full code is here:
https://github.com/bradtraversy/vue_crash_todolist

My Home.vue looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <AddTodo v-on:add-todo="addTodo"/>
    <Todos v-bind:todos="todos" v-on:del-todo="deleteTodo"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AddTodo from '../components/AddTodo'
import Todos from '../components/Todos'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    Todos,
    AddTodo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "Todo one",
          completed: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Todo two",
          completed: true
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Todo three",
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteTodo(id){
      this.todos = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id != id)
    },
    addTodo(newTodo){
      this.todos = [...this.todos, newTodo]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Whats important here is the Todos element in the markup. 
Its a complex component which imported TodoItem itself. 
Now Todos looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-bind:key="todo.id" v-for="todo in todos">
      <TodoItem v-bind:todo="todo" v-on:del-todo="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoItem from './TodoItem.vue'


export default {
  name: "Todos",
  components: {
    TodoItem
  },
  props: ["todos"]

}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

And it imported TodoItem, which is here:

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':todo.completed}">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete">
      {{todo.title}}
      <button @click="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)"class="del">x</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props:["todo"],
  methods: {
    markComplete(){
      this.todo.completed = !this.todo.completed
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>
  .todo-item {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc dotted;
  }
  .is-complete {
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
  .del {
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
  }
</style>
```

Now what confuses me is the syntax surrounding the emitted events. 
In TodoItem, I have this emitted event from the button:

```
<button @click="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)"class="del">x</button>
```

Now this is completely understandable for me because we have the event trigger specified with "@click". 
This is then exported to parent, Todos.vue, and there we can see this:

```
<TodoItem v-bind:todo="todo" v-on:del-todo="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)"/>
```

Here Im starting to get confused. 
Again, in the long syntax, a event trigger is defined:

```
v-on:del-todo
```

But del-todo is not an event trigger. Its neither click, nor change, nor input. 
So how can this code even work? What does vue.js imply when it encounters code like above?

My confusion then gets even worse in Home.vue

```
<Todos v-bind:todos="todos" v-on:del-todo="deleteTodo"/>
```

For the third time, an event trigger is specified.
And for the second time, this event trigger doesn't specify a "native" trigger like click.

Now I already wrapped my head around this and I could at least beat SOME sense into it. 
In Todos.vue and Home.vue, the specified events seem to execute when del-todo has fired. So they are like callbacks, they take the return value of del-todo.
In Todos.vue, triggering del-todo emits del-todo to its parent, Home.vue. 
Is that correct?

Home.vue then triggers deleteTodo when del-todo is fired. 
However, deleteTodo requires an id to be handed over through the parameter, but interestingly, `<Todos v-bind:todos="todos" v-on:del-todo="deleteTodo"/>` doesnt.
Still, the function works. So how does id ever arrive in deleteTodo?

A similar problem arises in TodoItem.vue. Here, del-todo is called, but actually we haven't any sort of declaration of this function anywhere in the script inside TodoItem.vue. So again, what does vueJS imply when it encounters a situation where a function is emitted/called which wasn't defined anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that each time you click there is an event AND value emitted to the parent component, the parent component has a listener `v-on:del-todo` means it is listening on the `del-todo` event, once it is triggered/handled it emits it again one level up until it reaches the component where you want to actually manipulate the data (delete the item based on id).
**Note**: the value is implicitly passed into the handler function `deleteTodo` so even though it is not explicitly there (i.e. `deleteTodo($event)` it is there.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue.js there are not only the events `click` `change` and `input`, it also allows you to define custom events. All you have to do ist throw an event in the child-component with `$emit('my-custom-event', param1, param2)` and catch it in the direct parent-component with `v-on:my-custom-event="handler"` (you can also write `@my-custom-event`, thats synonym). The handler is a function that takes the parameters passed when emitting the event. Your handler in the `Todos`-component catches the event `del-todo` and throws a new event with the same name. The `Home`-component catches that event and has its function `deleteTodo` defined as its handler, so this function is being called (the id that was passed with the event is the parameter for `deleteTodo`).